# C++ Comparing value from 2 different list to get rid of duplicate number using 2 for loop. Doesn't detect duplicate correctly

Tags: c++, for-loop, duplicates

```
ArrayBag foundBag;
    int z;
    z = getCurrentSize(); // tell you have many items exit in the bag
    for (int i = 0; i < z; i++ )
    {
        int cur = items[i]; //cur is use to hold each number in the vector and items is the first list of number.  
        bool found = false; // start as false so it doesnt trigger the true right away 
        for (int j = 0; j < foundBag.getCurrentSize(); j++) // this loop check the number currently inside cur agianst everything in the foundbag at the moment 
        {
            if (foundBag.items[i] = cur)  

            {
                found == true;   // << it didnt detect that it have found the number. I think the problem is here 
            }
        }
        if (found == true)
        {
            // do nothing if found since number is already in the foundbag
        }
        else if (found != true)
        {
            foundBag.add(cur); // if number is not found in the foundBag add it to the found bag.
        } 
    }
```

So what I m trying to do is comparing value from an existing list to a new empty one that is called foundBag in this case. So basically it suppose to get value from the first bag and then check if that number exit in the first bag or not then it will add that number to the foundBag if it did not find it. If it already found the number it will do nothing and move to the next element in the first bag.

say the first bag have number 3 4 5 7 5 8 it should add everything from 3 4 5 7 then do nothing when it get to the second 5 then add 8 to the foundBag. 
at the end foundBag should contain: 3 4 5 7 8

The problem is it doesnt seem to correctly detect that the number is already in the foundBag so it add everything.
I been using the step-over function in visual studio to look at each step but I couldnt figure out why the bool still go to false when it found the identical number.

*Im not very strong in english so if this doesnt make sense please ask for more explanation*

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have your `=` and `==` mixed up.

```
        if (foundBag.items[j] == cur)  // Use == here for comparison
        {
            found = true; // Use = here for assignment
        }
```

By the way, if all you're doing is looking for an element in a collection, prefer an algorithm from the standard library:

```
auto result = std::count(std::begin(foundBag.items), std::end(foundBag.items), cur);
if (result == std::end(foundBag.items)) {
    // Not found; Add it
    foundBag.add(cur);
}
```

Comment: You also look like you need to change the index from `i` to `j`.